# Get view from ViewPager before fragment finishing onCreateView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

Right now I have a ViewPager inside a fragment. I need to get/use some of the views in the first page of the ViewPager. My problem is how can I get those views right before finishing onCreateView method in the fragment?

Here are some of my codes:

MyFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    View firstView = myPagerAdapter.getFirstView();

    // I need to get the view of the first page and find TextView inside that view.
    // My problem is that firstView is null
    // since viewPager doesn't call instantiateItem yet when below sentence runs.
    mTextView = (TextView) firstView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    return mFragmentLayout;
}
```

MyPagerAdapter.java:

```
private View firstView;

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    View layout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mixin, collection, false);

    // Other logic to set the page

    if (position == 0) {
        firstView = layout;
    }
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

public View getFirstView() {
    return firstView;
}
```

Looks like ViewPager doesn't start initiating when I call getFirstView(), so I get null;

I can also pass a view from fragment into the ViewPager but I don't know how to do it, since it's only for the first page. How to only set the view of the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
 `ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);`

to

`ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) mFragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);`

Get ViewPager from your infaleted layout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) mFragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    View firstView = myPagerAdapter.getFirstView();

    // I need to get the view of the first page and find TextView inside that view.
    // My problem is that firstView is null
    // since viewPager doesn't call instantiateItem yet when below sentence runs.
    mTextView = (TextView) firstView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    return mFragmentLayout;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, firstView is still null since instantiateItemis not called yet